# how to bring some row next to each other?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column which is NA or an index of a row. I want to make a new data set and bring those rows next to each other.

example

```
            data      rowindex
            1         NA
            2         NA
            3         1,2
            4         5
            5         NA
```

here in row 3 , rowindex column is 1 and 2 so I will bring first and third row next to each other also second and third. Also  forth column of rowindex is 5 so I will bring forth and fifth row next to each other.

output

```
          data      rowindex      data.1      rowindex.1
            1         NA             3              1
            2         NA             3              1
            5         NA             4              5
```

I ignored to write down other columns. if we have 2 index then we have 2 different row in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems weird, but here you go:

```
ind = !is.na(dd$rowindex)
cbind(dd[dd$rowindex[ind], ],
      dd[ind, ])
#   data rowindex data rowindex
# 1    1       NA    3        1
# 5    5       NA    4        5
```

Using this data:

```
dd = read.table(text = 'data      rowindex
            1         NA
            2         NA
            3         1
            4         5
            5         NA', header= T)
```

Comment: Using the input at the bottom of my question, I get the output exactly as I show it. How is the input you're using different?

Comment: I guess the big difference between my solution and the others is that I treat `rowindex` as a *row number*, but the other answers so far treat `rowindex` as a *value* in the `data` column. As long as `data` is `1:n`, they are the same. But if they are different, there will be different results.

Comment: how about if I have 2 index in id? could you plz modify it in that case? I edited post

Comment: That's a lot more complicated. Rather than moving the goalposts after you've gotten and accepted a working answer, you should try it out yourself a bit and ask a new question if you can't get it to work. Look into `tidyr::separate_rows` to turn your comma-separated column into normal data. Your question is also somewhat vague about whether the `rowindex 1,2` refers to rows 1 and 2 or any rows with `data` values 1 and 2. If you ask a new question, please be specific on that. Perhaps use an example where the `data` values are not equal to the row number,  then your expected result will be clear.

Comment: rowindex is the index of rows of data frame.

Comment: right I can separate that column and try it again. thanks

Comment: "*rowindex is the index of rows of data frame.*" in that case, you may want to add a row-id column, because `separate_rows` will increase the number of rows in the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the community! Try this on:

```
df <- read.table(text="            data      rowindex
            1         NA
                 2         NA
                 3         1,2
                 4         5
                 5         NA",header=T)

## call in a library to manipulate text:
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

## And now use left_join() using the second column as the key:

## first throw away NAs, and split delimiters

df1 <-
  df %>% filter(!is.na(rowindex)) %>% mutate(ri = str_split(string = rowindex, pattern = ",")) %>% 
    unnest %>% mutate(ri = as.integer(ri))
df1

## now you can combine this one with the first one:
left_join(df1, df, by = c("ri" = "data"), )
```

You can find out more about left_join here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html